# Is there a word for a "promise breaker"?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I'm somewhat vexed in that I cannot think of a word that means a "promise breaker" or "person who breaks a promise". There are words that may subsume that, such as "miscreant" or "liar", but I cannot come up with an English word that is limited to a person who breaks promises.

The closest I've come is "piker", which is (a) informal and (b) limited to Australia/NZ, but means (according to the dictionary on my Mac):

> a person who withdraws from a commitment.

Is there a more formal and common word that can be used to refer to people who break promises?

Comment: What about *disloyal*?

Comment: @N.N. aside from /disloyal/ seeming to relate more to allegiance than obligation, /disloyal/ is an adjective not a noun. (A person is not "a disloyal", though they may be "a piker"). Good thought, though.

Comment: Are you looking for a single word that covers both willful (liar) and non-willful (flake) cases?  Or just one of those?

Comment: @MonicaCellio A word that covers both, but I'd err on the side of willful.

Comment: "**Liar**" is the word that comes to mind in a willful context _(e.g., "Most politicians are liars!")_.  "**Dishonoured**" or "**failed**" are two words that come to mind in a non-willful context _(e.g., "the payment was dishonoured by insufficient funds in the bank account" and "the new employee failed to arrive at the office on time," respectively)_.

Comment: "Piker" is used in America for someone who fails to live up to the terms of a bet. I don't think I've heard it used in other contexts.

Comment: @Randolf: But "liar" is more general. If I say, "Bob took your book" when it was really me who did it, I am a liar, but I have not broken any promise.

Comment: @Jay:  Indeed (good point, +1), many words have multiple uses.

Comment: Yes, there is: a ***break-promise***!

Comment: @MonicaCellio, I ended up here looking for non-willful/flake. Thanks for the distinction. I'd prefer something more formal than flake, that would describe, say, a slick, expensive government contractor that promises the world and delivers an overdue, over-budget mess. Any suggestions? (Maybe **nonperformer**, **deadbeat**, ...)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**[Reneger](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reneger)**:

> **renege, renegue** vb (intr; often foll by on)
>   to go back (on one's promise, etc.)
>   **reneger , reneguer** n

[*Reneger* vs. *oath breaker* ngram:](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reneger,oath%20breaker&year_start=1920&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

[image: ngram of 'reneger' and 'oath breaker' 1920-2010, reneger leading in use approx 1960, oath breaker leading in use approx 1930s and early 2000s]

Comment: "Renege" is indeed the conventional verb to use for this idea. But while the dictionary lists "reneger" as a noun, I'm hard-pressed to recall ever seeing it used in real text. (Not that I can think of an alternative word.)

Comment: That's what happens with "one word" requests.  There may be none that is well-known.

Comment: I don't think we're going to get any closer than this.

Comment: I've seen it in legal contexts, but with the 'u'.

Comment: I would highly advise against using this word in converstation unless you have complete faith in your ability to pronounce it properly and clearly. It is just way too close to this word: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9824/was-the-word-nigger-an-expletive-in-mark-twains-day

Comment: ... this still isn't perfect - reneging has more of a "going back" feeling rather than "breaking". But it's

Comment: Now that's a strange-looking ngram. I wonder if political rhetoric is mostly to blame for the two terms going in and out of fashion...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sometimes I wonder if the percentages on some of these ngrams aren't so small as to effectively make them noise graphs.

Comment: Too small for statistics, perhaps.  But think of it as an answer to: "Is it ever used in real text?"  We can click there and attempt to find some real texts.

Comment: It's **always** a good idea to include a link to where you got that information. Otherwise it's plagiarism

Answer (score 27):

A personal favorite slang term for an unreliable person is a ***[flake](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-of/flake)***.  A flake says they are going to do something and then they don't follow through.  The definition is not limited to promise breaking, however.

Comment: Yeah, not limited to promise breaker, but it's a good word in the context though. My mother used the word "flakey" a lot.

Comment: Is it okay to refer to an _unreliable corn farmer_ as a "**corn flake**?"  ;D

Answer (score 16):

There's "oathbreaker". It isn't very common these days though.

Comment: Not in regular speech... way common in fantasy literature, though.

Answer (score 12):

**[Warlock](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/warlock)** - if you're into really *Old* English:

> Middle English warloghe, from Old English wrloga, oath-breaker : wr,
>   pledge; see wr-o- in Indo-European roots + -loga, liar (from logan, to
>   lie; see leugh- in Indo-European roots).

(Note: the link originally went to Wikipedia's [Warlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warlock), which had a brief description, including roughly the *oathbreaker* meaning. Apparently the word has changed, to a D&D character...)

Comment: I love this as a historical meaning. However, today it is pretty much universally understood to be "somebody (typically male) who practices magic". If you try to use it for the meaning above, you will probably be misunderstood.

Answer (score 9):

This may be US specific, but I have used Welcher used for promises as well as bets.

Comment: It's not US only, but it's slang and is best avoided as it can be offensive to Welsh people. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=welch http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=417491

Comment: I remember someone once using the word "gypped" in high school, which caused one girl to object -- she explained that she is of Gypsy heritage and that this word reflects poorly on her background in an unjust manner.  (I thought she made a fair point, and out of respect for people in general I've made an effort to eliminate these sorts of words from my casual speech as I discover their meanings; _this has been a challenge because I've never encountered a list of such words_.)

Comment: @RandolfRichardson That might make a good question ...

Comment: @Brian M. Hunt:  Great idea!  Here's the link to that question (which I put a fair effort into writing):  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44281/mildly-offensive-words-and-phrases-that-describe-cultures-or-identifiable-groups

Comment: @RandolfRichardson: Great attempt; I'm sorry for the reaction it got, but I do think it was a great idea. I wonder if someday it'll be revived and accepted.

Comment: @Brian M. Hunt:  Once you mentioned it I thought "yeah, that would be a good question" but I guess both of us are still "learning the ropes" around here.  :)

Comment: That use might be considered a ethnic slur against those of welsh descent.

Comment: @Neuromancer - Already mentioned by Hugo, 2 1/2 years ago.

Answer (score 4):

## Is there a word for a “promise breaker”?

### Yes, there is: ***break-promise***!

And yes, this is a person who breaks a promise. It was used by no less than William Shakespeare in *As You Like It* and is in a category of nouns called ***cutthroat compounds***.

According to [Encyclopedia Briannica](http://www.encyclopediabriannica.com/?p=57):

> Cutthroats are compounds that name people and things by describing what they do. Cutthroats are made from a transitive verb and a noun, where the noun is the direct object of the verb.

So a *cutthroat* is not a throat but a pirate who cuts throats; a *scarecrow* is not a crow but a thing that scares crows; a *Shakespeare* is a person who originally shook spears; and a *break-promise* is a person who breaks promises.

Some other *break-* cutthroats:

- *break-bones* (an osprey)
- *break-club* (an obstacle in golf)
- *break-hedge* (a trespasser)
- *break-league* (a treaty breaker)
- *break-love* (a disturber of love)
- *break-net* (a dogfish)
- *break-peace*
- *break-pulpit* (a break-pulpit preacher)
- *break-vow*
- *breakwind*

Comment: Yeah, well, if you want to use an obsolete word that takes quite a bit of explaining.

Comment: I think it's quite self-explanatory! Before I posted this, I heard it in some Shakespeare and it was immediately self-evident. The explanation is trying to give a useful and informative answer, as all answers should be here.

Answer (score 2):

A more formal version of OP's suggested word Piker is Defaulter

Answer (score 2):

***recreant***

> *adj.* Unfaithful or disloyal to a belief, duty, or cause: *"Consider the man who stands by his duty and goes to the stake rather than be recreant to it"* (Mark Twain).
>
> *n.* A faithless or disloyal person.
>
> [Middle English recreaunt, defeated, from Old French recreant, present participle of recroire, to yield in a trial by combat, surrender allegiance, from Medieval Latin recrēdere, to yield, pledge : Latin re-, re- + Latin crēdere, to believe; see kerd- in Indo-European roots.][American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/recreant)

***apostate***

> *n.* A disloyal person who betrays or deserts their cause or religion or political party or friend etc.
>
> *adj.* Not faithful to religion or party or cause [WordNet 3.0, Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/apostate)

Answer (score 1):

Let me add *forsworn*. Which is one of those words with two opposite senses, as "He forswore alcohol," with the sense of making the promise followed by "He went on a drunken bender and was forsworn."

Answer (score 1):

Faithless is one possibility. From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/faithless):

> 4. Not observant of promises or covenants.

Unfaithful or perfidious may be possibilities as well.

Answer (score 0):

I call someone who breaks a promise to me a betrayer. But "reneger" is probably a better choice.

Comment: Betrayal is too strong a word unless the promise was something very important and personal; Brian said nothing to indicate that the offending person would necessarily have broken so important a trust.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just in the area of love, it could be 'heart-breaker'.