# Clarification of definition of liar

Tags: meaning

Stating to a friend with full intention: "I'm not going to write the person that did me wrong". Then later changing your mind and sending a letter. Then telling friend what you did. Are you defined as a liar?

I was a victim of domestic violence. Ex-fiance is in jail awaiting trial. I stated to a friend I would not communicate with ex-fiance anymore. Weeks later I sent a letter. I shared this information with my friend who then states I was lying to him by stating initially I wouldn't do this. Without intentions of deception and believing myself that I wouldn't is my initial statement of intentions defined as a lie?

Comment: I believe you mean 'Liar'; as in a person who tells lies, instead of lier, which means one who rests or reclines

Comment: Yes, my oversight.

Comment: To receive a satisfactory answer on this question you'll need to provide more clarification about the situation. Otherwise you can just search 'liar' and see if your case matches up with the definition

Comment: Possibly related: [Is there a word for a “promise breaker”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44251)

Answer (score 2):

According to definitions, what you did would not be considered a *lie* because you didn't possess a deliberate intent to deceive.

Lie:

> 1. a false statement made with deliberate intent to deceive; an intentional untruth; a falsehood.
> 2. something intended or serving to convey a false impression; imposture:

Words that would better fit your case would be deceive or mislead

Deceive:

> to mislead by a false appearance or statement; delude:

Mislead:

> to lead or guide wrongly; lead astray.

Source for definitions: http://www.dictionary.com/