# What do you call someone who comes up with excuses, so they don't have to do something that they said they will?

Tags: expressions

For example, when someone "pinky promises" something and then when they have to do what they promised they don't want to do they come up with excuses, for example they'll say "I never said it promises a time of when I will do it". What are words to call a person like this, basically someone who doesn't keep their word, but I need other works.

Comment: This is awfully close to https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44251/is-there-a-word-for-a-promise-breaker

Comment: A _politician_, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I think such a person is [flake](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flake)

Flake: a person you can not trust to remember things or to do what they promise

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/282461)

Comment: @JJJ I added the essential part to my answer but I really don't know what else I should add to my answer in oder to not to be a low-quality post !! So you can delete this post if it really does not provide the answer cause I don't know how to explain it in  other way !anyway,thanks for your feedback !!

Comment: It's better this way, now someone who reads your answer immediately knows what the word you mention means. Thanks for changing it. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your example:

> *for example they'll say "I never said it promises a time of when I will do it".*

They actually didn't break a promise or tell a lie, they just cheated.

So, I would call them [cheater](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cheater).

> A person who acts dishonestly in order to gain an advantage. (Oxford)