# Is there a word for the victim of a broken promise

Tags: single-word-requests

Related question: *[Is there a word for a "promise breaker"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44251/is-there-a-word-for-a-promise-breaker)*

I want to refer to the victim of a broken promise. A [quick search online](https://www.google.be/search?q=promisee) led me to believe that *promisee* is an acceptable word but it sounds a bit childish to me.

Comment: One option would be _jilted_, which mainly applies to romantic relationships. This is mainly used as an adjective, but could also be used nominally. The breaker would be a _jilt_ or _jilter_.

Comment: _promisee_ refers to the recipient of any promise, even ones that were kept

Comment: @rosslh So, it is a real word? Could I use _victim promisee_ as a condensed version of _victim of a broken promise_? At least that gets me down to two words; that would be an acceptable alternative for now.

Comment: I think there is not, for the same reason there aren't, broadly, separate terms for victims of anything, including assaultees, batterees, burglarees, rapees, robbees, stealees… yet we don't.

Comment: You could refer to that person as **the promised**

Comment: There isn't a single word: there are adjectives and nouns. The betrayed etc. only work in very literary contexts. promisee is above all a legal term, imo: promisor, promisee

Comment: _Injured party_. Or the obscure _breachee_ which Garner's really hate. But that's all legalese. Maybe futher [context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/450068/is-there-a-word-for-the-victim-of-a-broken-promise#comment1517751_602148) would help.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was *jilted*, but I see that someone has already commented on that.

So, you might use **The betrayed**.

To *betray* someone is "to break faith with, [to] fail to meet the hopes of, to lead astray; deceive... to seduce and then desert [someone]."
([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/betray))

*The betrayed*, then, would be someone who was "treacherously abandoned, deserted, or mistreated." ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/betrayed))

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help). You will see that on this site the users are encouraged to support the answers they give with references from reputable sources.

Comment: What do you want me to do? I can start linking the definitions of the words if that would help.

Comment: Like fev, I too emphasise the importance of reading the help centre. Good  answers often refer to a source such as a dictionary, perhaps give example usage, and do not engage in much peripheral comment.

Comment: makes sense, I'll change this to be like my other updated answers sometime soon. They waited four and a half years for a good answer: waiting another couple days for citations won't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

The term *aggrieved* fits generally for people damaged by the actions of others, including this case:

> unhappy and angry because of unfair treatment

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/aggrieved)

As indicated by @RobbieGoodwin's comment, English tends to name offending actions in terms of the offender, not the offended.

Comment: Can you share the type of promise broken?  I suspect the answer you're seeking will not be an individual word, but a context related turn of phrase.  Promisor and Promisee are rarely used outside of legal contracts.