# Word for refusing to do what you're supposed to

Tags: single-word-requests

What's another word that describes that act of not doing what you're supposed to do?

Eg: The electoral voter did not vote for his state's preferred candidate. He [the word]'ed.

"Reneged" doesn't quite sound right.

Comment: Do you want a word specific to the electoral college? If not, this is the duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/44251/191178

Comment: "Unfaithful elector" is the term normally used.

Comment: Depending on the context, but the following could be used, declined, resisted, abstained, withstand/withstood, disobliged